# How to Create a Thumbnail Picture for an OLE Object from a Table in a Word Document using C# and Open XML

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am working on a C# project where I need to replace a table in a Microsoft Word document with an OLE object of itself using the Open XML library. I've managed to embed a new Word document containing the table and insert it at the correct location. However, I'm struggling to figure out how to create the mandatory thumbnail picture for the OLE object.

Here's what I've done so far:

1. Extracted the table from the Word document.
2. Embedded it into a new Word document as an OLE object.
3. Inserted this OLE object into the original document.

The OLE object is properly inserted, but it doesn't have a thumbnail image, and it appears as an icon. I want to generate a thumbnail picture for the OLE object so that it visually represents the table within the Word document.

Is there a way to programmatically generate this thumbnail image for the OLE object using C# and the Open XML library, or do I need to use a different approach or library to achieve this? Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated.